# Infinite nested windows when connecting through VNC

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, vnc, vncviewer

I am trying to connect to my VNC server that i have setup in my ubuntu 16.04
*i have tried the default out of the box vnc server Desktop-Sharing i have tried x11vnc. When i connect the connection works fine but after connection this happens*

**here i connect through localhost using vncviewer from RealVNC**

[image]

**here i connect through the windows 7 os that is running on virtualbox in bridged networking mode  i am using Vncviewer from RealVnc to connect to the vnc server**

[image]

*i am using this command to run x11vnc*

```
sudo x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /home/shady/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared
```

**what is happening ? and how to avoid this**

Comment: It's happening presumably because you are running the VNC viewer on the same desktop that you're connecting to?

Comment: i was connecting through a windows box that was running on virtualbox

Comment: with a bridged network adapter

Comment: ok i will do that

Comment: So... you are running an Ubuntu desktop, within which you are running a Windows VM, and in the Windows VM you are running a VNC viewer which you connect to the Ubuntu desktop... within which you are running a Windows VM, and in the Windows VM you are running a VNC viewer which you connect to the Ubuntu desktop... within which you are running a Windows VM, and in the Windows VM you are running a VNC viewer which you connect to the Ubuntu desktop...  ?

Comment: Exactly ! right